# Replace entire row based on duplicates columns in csv file

Tags: csv, replace

I have two csv files, each of which has two columns.  File A is the master file which contains the order of the items, which is important.  File B has some (but not all) updated information that needs to replace the old information in file A.

How do I replace the old values in column 2 of file A with the new values from column 2 of file B, but only where the values in column 1 are duplicates?

For example:

###### File A

| Name | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Bob Smith | 12 |
| Mary West | 67 |
| Joe Soap | 77 |
| Edith Little | 41 |

###### File B

| Name | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Mary West | 83 |
| Edith Little | 16 |

###### Desired result

| Name | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Bob Smith | 12 |
| Mary West | 83 |
| Joe Soap | 77 |
| Edith Little | 16 |

I feel like there should be a simple solution to this that I'm just missing, but I haven't had any luck with searching for a method.

Edit:
I attempted to solve the problem using replace duplicates in google sheets, which resulted in the correct values, but the order was lost.  I ran up against the same problem using Sublime Text in that I can keep the new values quite easily, but I can't seem to find a way to keep them in the position of the old values.

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: I didn't think my experience would be useful to explain, but I've added it.

Comment: If you post what you actually tried (as opposed to short descriptions), someone might be able to help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
=INDEX(IFNA({Q2:Q7,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Q2:Q7,T2:U5,2,0),R2:R9)}))
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]